# setting .indexOn without knowing full path in firebase

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on an example app for learning purposes, it is a chat app. The data in firebase database will be structured as shown below. My problem is, I need to be able to order messages based on their createdOn key, but as you can see from the database structure there is no way I can know the full path of the messages in advance, since every time a user starts a new private chat it will create a new path and the messages will be in that new path. Is there some way to set an index on a top level parent and it filters down to the lower levels?
Database structure...

```
{
  "chat": {
    "channels": {
      "{CHANNELID}": {
        "title": "public channel",
        "description": "A meeting place",
        "createdOn": {new Date().getTime()}
      },
      ...
    },
    "private_chat": {
      "{USERID}": {
        "channels": {
          "{CHANNELID}": "{USERID}",
          ...
        },
        "messages": {
          "{CHANNELID}": {
            "{MESSAGEID}": {
              "from": "{USERID}",
              "createdOn": {new Date().getTime()}
              "message": "Hi There"
            },
            ...
          },
          ...
       }
     },
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

So, I would be getting "/chat/private_chat/{user_id}/messages/{channel_id}" and then order by "createdOn", but like I said, there is no way I could know the full path of that to create an index on in the database. Is there a way to set it on "/chat/private_chat" then it automatically filters down to the children?
Thank you.

Comment: You can have variables for the keys in your rules.  Have you tried that?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#location

Comment: Oh man, I feel a little idiotic right now. I had completely forgotten about that. I have been working on this chat thing for so long my brain just checked out. Thank you @dou